# How to get www.torproject.org signing keys?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security

Where to get signing keys to verify Tor browser bundle?
I'm using Debian Wheezy and cannot find where I can get them to import them using gpg.

Answer (score 3):

Information about Tor Project keys is [here](https://www.torproject.org/docs/signing-keys.html.en).  The one for the browser bundle is Erinn Clark (0x63FEE659).

```
gpg2 --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv 0x63FEE659
```